# Creating a Jest Unit Test for Express Middleware function

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to create unit tests for Express middleware functions, by checking if the NextFunction has been called.

SecurityWrapper.test.ts

```js
let mockRequest: Partial<Request>;
let mockResponse: Partial<Response>;
const nextFunction: NextFunction = jest.fn();

test("validates ownership correctly", () => {
  const security = new SecurityWrapper("config.json");
  mockRequest = {
    accessToken: new AccessToken("token"),
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer token"},
    params: {id: "xxx-yyy"}
  };

  const uri = "https://myresource.uri";

  mocked(Utils).getClientServiceAccountToken.mockResolvedValueOnce("token");

  mock.onGet(uri).reply(200, { owner: { id: "Mr. Bean"}});

  AccessToken.prototype.decode = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({sub: "Mr. Bean"});

  const owner = security.validateOwnership();
  owner(mockRequest as Request, mockResponse as Response, nextFunction);

  expect(nextFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

SecurityWrapper.ts

```js
import validateOwnership from "./middleware/validateOwnership";
// ...
validateOwnership (resId?: string) {
  return validateOwnership(this.config, resId);
}
// ...
```

validateOwnership.ts

```js
export default function validateOwnership (config: Config, resId?: string) {
  return function owner (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction):
    void {
    const id = resId ? resId : req.params.id;

    if (id === undefined) {
      res.sendStatus(400);
      return;
    }
    const clientBasicAuth = config.clientCredentials;

    if (clientBasicAuth === undefined || clientBasicAuth.length === 0) {
      res.sendStatus(400);
      return;
    }

    fetchResourceOwner(config, id, `${clientBasicAuth}`)
      .then((owner) => {
        const own = req.accessToken.decode().sub;
        if (owner === own) {
          // This function does get called by the tests, but test always fails regardless
          next();
          return;
        } else {
          res.sendStatus(403);
          return;
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        res.sendStatus(401);
      });
  };
}
```

The `nextFunction` mock does get called (checked via mockImplementation with logging to console) but the test always fails. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is a fail comment you get while doing this?

Comment: @Shrirang The failure comment is:

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validateOwnership` calles `next` function asynchronously, therefore `expect` check happens before `next` has been called. Usually you want to fix that by using async tests.
In this case it might look like this:

```js
test("validates ownership correctly", async () => {
  // setup code

  // we convert callback to promise
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    owner(mockRequest as Request, mockResponse as Response, () => {
      resolve();
      nextFunction();
    });
  });

  expect(/* ... */);
});
```

If you only check that `next` have been called you might not even need mock `nextFunction`, because if promise is not resolved, test will fail with timeout error:

```js
await new Promise(resolve => owner(mockRequest as Request, mockResponse as Response, resolve));
```

Comment: This does do the trick for the test to pass, thanks!